# RxJava: How can I wrap a multi-step operation, returning the step complete to observers?

Tags: java, rx-java2

Lets say I have a login and user data method, representing HTTP calls:

```
Single<LoginResponse> login();
Single<UserData> userData();
```

I need to call `login()` then `userData()`. If both succeed, the user is logged in.

I know how to wrap them up in a e.g. `Completable`:

```
Completable performLogin() {
    login().doOnSuccess(this::storeLoginResponse)
        .flatMap(userData())
        .doOnSuccess(this::storeUserData)
        .doOnError(this::wipeLoginData)
        .toCompletable();
}
```

So the UI then says

```
showLoading();
performLogin().subscribe(() -> {
    stopLoading();
    onLoginSuccess();
}, error -> {
    stopLoading();
    onLoginFailure();
});
```

What if the UI needs to show which stage of the loading is happening? As in, when the `login()` call completes and the `userData()` call starts it will change the UI?

What I thought of is something like

```
Observable<LoginStage> performLogin() {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        login.doOnSuccess(response -> {
            storeLoginResponse(response)
            emitter.onNext(LOGIN_COMPLETE)
        }).flatMap(userData())
        .subscribe(userData -> {
            storeUserData(userData);
            emitter.onNext(USER_DATA_COMPLETE)
            emitter.onComplete();
        }, error -> {
            wipeLoginData();
            emitter.onError(error);
        });
    });
}
```

But it feels like there's a nicer or more Rx-y way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hot observables and chain one observable to another Subject and pass all items form one emission to another if you need it.

```
@Test
public void chainObservablesWithSubject() throws InterruptedException {
    Observable<Long> observable = Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1l, 2l, 3l, 4l));
    Subject<Long, Long> chainObservable = ReplaySubject.create(1);
    observable.subscribe(chainObservable);
    chainObservable.subscribe(System.out::println, (e) -> System.err.println(e.getMessage()), System.out::println);
}
```

You can check more examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/connectable/HotObservable.java